# NEO-6M GPS Module Not Working

Tags: usb, power, gps

I have an RS232 NEO-6M GPS module connected to my Raspberry Pi. The board I have requires power, ground, TX and RX. Power and ground are connected to my Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins (+5V and GND), and the TX/RX pins are connected to a USB to RS232 DB-9 Serial adapter which is also plugged into the RPi. I can confirm that I am getting NEMA sentences from the GPS module, however it is always the same sentence over and over:

$GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50

It seems to me that there is a power related issue since it looks like the GPS module may be resetting (when researching online it seems like it should be printing out more than just that line). I made sure I am using a good 2A USB adapter/cable to power the RPi and also tried using 3.3V to power the NEO-6M board instead, but I didn't get any sentences printing out with that voltage. The NEO-6M board that I have contains a 3V regulator on it so it should require  5V to power it. Is there anything else that I can try to solve this problem?

Comment: suggestions: (1) Put aside Rpi, try Win10 ublox neo center ide, first, to make sure basic setup is OK. (2) read my neo-xm set up log: 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519711/gps-taking-long-time-to-fix-out-in-the-open. Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: Hasn't the NEO-6M GPS usually UART interface?

Comment: Possible that the GPS just has no signal. I've seen similar quite a few times on GPS modules for me its always been a signal issue. Try moving it outside and see if that makes a difference, also some modules can take a while to get a proper fix. Set it up and leave it for 15 mins to make sure its had chance to get a good fix.